# Django serializers filter foreignkey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

view:

```
  class MPNView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset =  MPN.objects.all()
      serializer_class = MPNSerializer
```

serializers:

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
      model = Products
      fields = "__all__"

class MPNSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  products = ProductsSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
      model = MPN
      fields = "__all__"
```

model:

```
class MPN(Model):
  number     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Product(Model):
  mpn           = models.ForeignKey(to=MPN, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", null=True, blank=True)
  created_at    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Results i am getting:

```
  [
        {
            "id": 1221,
            "products": [],
            "number": "B07BMTYSMR",
            "created_at": "2020-09-29T03:05:01.560801Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 1222,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 2352,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-30T12:49:09.347655Z",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2352,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-30T12:49:09.347655Z",
                }
              ]
          }
    ]
```

Results i am expecting:

```
  [
        {
            "id": 1222,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 2352,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-30T12:49:09.347655Z",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2352,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-30T12:49:09.347655Z",
                }
              ]
          }
  ]
```

Here is my code . I have shared view, model and serializers.

Here I am trying to get result with ForeignKey related fields.

But, I want to add one filter so that it ignores data where products is [ ] (empty array)

> Please have a look how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try filtering the queryset:

```
queryset =  MPN.objects.all().exclude(products__isnull=True)
```

Here you would use the "products" and check if it is empty. Empty results would be excluded.